# Equation of tangent plane to a surface at certain point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

So I am solving for an equation of a tangent plane to surface $z=x + \ln(2x+y)$ at the point $(-1,3,-1)$. I know I need to take partial derivative of that equation and plug in the point of the formula. I did everything and I got: $-3x-y+z+1=0$. Is it the correct answer?

Here is how I got it:
    $$F_x = -1 - \frac{2}{2x+y};\quad F_y = - \frac{1}{2x+y};\quad F_z = 1$$
    if I plug everything into $F_x$, $F_y$, $F_z$, I get  $(-3,-1,1)$. Then I plug these number into the formula $-3(x+1)-(y-3)+(z+1)=0$. Is this the right way?

Comment: It seems correct.